# Helm upgrading chart to specific version and use default latest version

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a bash script used in a pipeline to upgrade a Helm chart to use the latest version.

```
helm upgrade \
"${HELM_ENV_RELEASE}" \
"chart-museum/${HELM_CHART}" \
--set-string pod.name="${POD_NAME}" \
--values "${VALUES_FILE}" \
--install \
--force \
--namespace "${K8S_NAMESPACE}" \
--timeout 180s \
--wait;
```

Now sometimes, I want to use an older version. I was thinking of adding a condition and adding a variable HELM_VERSION and use it with the option `--version`, like the following:

```
if ${HELM_VERSION}!='' // if the helm version is specified and is not empty

helm upgrade \
...
--version "${HELM_VERSION}" 
else                  // if not, then the helm chart should use the latest version

helm upgrade \
...

fi
```

Is this the right way to do it ? Maybe there is a default variable I can use if none is specified, like latest in Docker?

Comment: To answer your query related to install the latest version, yes! You can just ignore specifying the `--version` flag when you need to upgrade to the latest chart version.

Answer (score 0):

The `helm install --version` option takes a semantic-version constraint, not necessarily a fixed version number.  A constraint like `> 0` will match any (non-development) version and can be used as a default.

You can combine this with the Bourne shell default-value syntax to do

```bash
helm upgrade \
  --version "${HELM_VERSION:->0}" \
  ...
```

(Inside `"`double quotes`"`, to protect from values containing spaces and other non-alphanumeric characters; inside `${`braces`}` to explicitly indicate a parameter expansion; the variable `HELM_VERSION`; or `:-` if unset or empty, the default `>0`.)